# Android app won't start and doesn't list errors/warnings. Using fragments and issue seems to be with var args = ViewFragmentArgs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm trying to build a calculator app that looks like:
[image of calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjD02.png)

The display portion and keyboard portion are separate fragments, and the keyboard fragment needs to update the display fragment.

The gradle files have been updated according to Jetpack for safe args and navigation. Also, I am using view binding and everything has been updated accordingly.

The following code is for the fragment keyboard file that is sending information to the display file (I think this portion is ok, but I may have issues with the last line since it is what sends the data to the display file -> findNavController().navigate(KeysFragmentDirections.actionKeysFragmentToViewFragment(completeNumber)))

```
package com.test.cis2818_proj2.ui.main

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.test.cis2818_proj2.databinding.FragmentKeysBinding

class KeysFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentKeysBinding
    var completeNumber = ""
    var operand1 = 0.0f
    var operand2 = 0.0f
    var operation = ""

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = FragmentKeysBinding.inflate(inflater)

        binding.keysFragmentBt0.setOnClickListener { createNumber("0") }
        binding.keysFragmentBt1.setOnClickListener { createNumber("1") }
        binding.keysFragmentBt2.setOnClickListener { createNumber("2") }
        binding.keysFragmentBt3.setOnClickListener { createNumber("3") }
        binding.keysFragmentBt4.setOnClickListener { createNumber("4") }
        binding.keysFragmentBt5.setOnClickListener { createNumber("5") }
        binding.keysFragmentBt6.setOnClickListener { createNumber("6") }
        binding.keysFragmentBt7.setOnClickListener { createNumber("7") }
        binding.keysFragmentBt8.setOnClickListener { createNumber("8") }
        binding.keysFragmentBt9.setOnClickListener { createNumber("9") }
        binding.keysFragmentBtDot.setOnClickListener { createNumber(".") }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun createNumber(stringNum: String) {
        if (completeNumber == "" && stringNum == ".") {
            completeNumber = "0"
        }

        if (completeNumber == "" && stringNum == "0") {
            completeNumber = ""
        } else {
            completeNumber += stringNum
        }

        binding.keysFragmentTvTester.text = completeNumber

       findNavController().navigate(KeysFragmentDirections.actionKeysFragmentToViewFragment(completeNumber))

    }
}
```

Here is all of the code for the display file:

```
package com.test.cis2818_proj2.ui.main

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.test.cis2818_proj2.databinding.FragmentViewBinding

class ViewFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentViewBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentViewBinding.inflate(inflater)

        var args = ViewFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
        binding.viewFragmentTvDisplay.text = args.displayData

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

The issue seems to be with the following code:

```
    var args = ViewFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
    binding.viewFragmentTvDisplay.text = args.displayData
```

When I delete this code the app runs and looks fine. With the code in the app, it doesn't start at all and crashes.

Any help in understanding where my issue is is appreciated!

Here is the navigation.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/keysFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/keysFragment"
        android:name="com.test.cis2818_proj2.ui.main.KeysFragment"
        android:label="fragment_keys"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_keys" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_keysFragment_to_viewFragment"
            app:destination="@id/viewFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/viewFragment"
        android:name="com.test.cis2818_proj2.ui.main.ViewFragment"
        android:label="fragment_view"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_view" >
        <argument
            android:name="display_data"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Error from logcat (not sure if this is the same thing as stack trace... sorry)

```
2021-11-07 15:42:59.034 20955-20955/com.test.cis2818_proj2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.cis2818_proj2, PID: 20955
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ViewFragment{f3bb415} (4c06d0b7-8565-4b91-b844-7e691229f22c id=0x7f0a0106) does not have any arguments.
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireArguments(Fragment.java:748)
        at com.test.cis2818_proj2.ui.main.ViewFragment.onCreateView(ViewFragment.kt:19)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Here is the main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/desert_sand"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_ct_view_fragment"
        android:name="com.test.cis2818_proj2.ui.main.ViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_view" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView2"
        android:name="com.test.cis2818_proj2.ui.main.KeysFragment"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_activity_ct_view_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_keys" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.test.cis2818_proj2

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    }
}
```

Also, here is frament_keys.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/desert_sand"
    tools:context=".ui.main.KeysFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_1"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_clear_entry"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_clear_entry"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_clear_entry" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_2"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_3"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_subtract"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_8"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_8"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_9"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_mult"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_electric_blue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_multiply"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_6"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_6"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_mult"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_7"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_7"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_modulus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_modulus"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_modulus" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_div"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_electric_blue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_divide"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_4"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_sqrt"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_sqrt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_sqrt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_sqrt"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_electric_blue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_sqrt"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_clear_entry"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_modulus"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_electric_blue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_modulus"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_sqrt"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_5"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_9"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_9"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_div"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_dot"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_dot"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_neg_sign"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_equals"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_electric_blue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_equals"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_clear_all" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_add"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_electric_blue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_add"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_neg_sign"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_neg_sign"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_neg_sign" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_clear_all"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_electric_blue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_clear_all"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_clear_entry" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_0"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_clear_all"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_dot"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_clear_all"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_clear_all" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_neg_sign"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/rich_black_fogra_29"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_neg_sign"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_dot"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_add"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_dot"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_dot" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_clear_entry"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_electric_blue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_clear_entry"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_subtract"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_electric_blue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/squada_one"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_subtract"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/keys_fragment_tv_tester"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tester"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/keys_fragment_bt_equals" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: So what's the crash message? Please include the entire stack trace.

Comment: Sorry I'm new. Is the stack trace the logcat?

Comment: Yes, you've got the right stack trace. It looks like from that message that you've directly added the `ViewFragment` to your Activity's `supportFragmentManager` either directly or via your layout XML, totally separately from the call to `navigate()` which would replace your `KeysFragment` with your `ViewFragment`. Is that what you're doing? Can you include your activity code and the activity's layout XML?

Comment: If I understand your question... Yes. Instead of replacing KeysFragment with ViewFragment, I am adding both to the main_activity.xml and trying to update the ViewFragment directly.

Answer (score 0):

The [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) involves using a single `NavHostFragment` in your Activity that figures out what fragment needs to be displayed by using your navigation graph. Each call to `navigate()` replaces the current fragment with the new fragment.

You aren't using a `NavHostFragment` in your activity XML and don't actually want any replacing of one fragment with another. Instead, your two fragments are sibling fragments - two, independently added fragments that both exist in your activity's layout. This isn't something you'd use Navigation, its navigation graph, or Safe Args for.

Instead, you'd want to [Communicate between fragments using the Fragment Result API](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result). This API is made specifically for sending information between fragments - such as between your ViewFragment and KeyFragment.

This means your `ViewFragment` would look more like:

```
class ViewFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentViewBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentViewBinding.inflate(inflater)

        // Uses the Kotlin extension available in fragment-ktx
        setFragmentResultListener("keySelected") { _, bundle ->
            val displayData = bundle.getString("displayData")
            binding.viewFragmentTvDisplay.text = args.displayData
        }

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

And your `KeysFragment`'s `createNumber` would look more like:

```
private fun createNumber(stringNum: String) {
    if (completeNumber == "" && stringNum == ".") {
        completeNumber = "0"
    }

    if (completeNumber == "" && stringNum == "0") {
        completeNumber = ""
    } else {
        completeNumber += stringNum
    }

    binding.keysFragmentTvTester.text = completeNumber

    // Uses the Kotlin extension in fragment-ktx
    setFragmentResult("keySelected", bundleOf("displayData" to completeNumber))

}
```